# How to get unique list of values from two columns?

Tags: php, laravel

I have table named projectlist as below. I would like to get list of cities from each country & list of projects from each city

```
-Country    City        Project    
-India      Chennai     Project1    
India       Hyderabad   Project2    
India       Delhi       Project3    
India       Mumbai      Project4    
India       Bangalore   Project5    
USA         Shreveport  Project6    
USA         Chicago     Project7    
USA         New York    Project8    
USA         Huston      Project9    
Germany     Berlin      Project10    
Germany     Munich      Project11    
Germany     Framkfurt   Project12    
India       Hyderabad   Project13    
India       Bangalore   Project14    
USA         Shreveport  Project15    
Germany     Berlin      Project16    
Germany     Munich      Project17
```

I have the below code in my laravel controller. I know that the below code is a wrong approach, please guide me with sample codes.
And I would like to return this value and display in blade view

```
$data4 = DB::table('loksabha2014')
       ->select(
        DB::raw('alliance as alliance','partyname as partyname'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
       ->groupBy('alliance')
       ->get();
```

I would like to display as below in my blade view

Cities List:

```
India - Chennai, Hyderabad, Delhi, Mumbai, Bangalore    
USA - Shreveport, Chicago, New York, Huston     
Germany - Berlin, Munich, Framkfurt
```

Project List:

```
Chennai - Project1    
Hyderabad - Project2, Project13    
Delhi - Project3    
Bangalore - Project14    
Shreveport - Project6, Project15    
Chicago - Project7    
New York - Project8     
Huston - Project9     
Berlin - Project10, Project16    
Munich - Project11, Project17
```

Comment: How is that laravel code relevant to the table? What kind of results are you expecting? You say "I would like to display as below in my blade view" but you have not provided the example.

Comment: tshimkus: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I missed that information. I have updated my post. Please check that now

Comment: I don't know Laravel but I know a thing or two about databases. I think you'll want something like: `$cities = DB::table('projectlist')->select('country', 'city')->groupBy('country')->get();` and `$projectsByCity = DB::table('projectlist')->select('city', 'project')->groupBy('city')->get();`